# Problema con ejercicio en Java NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy necesitando ejecutar correctamente el inicio de un programa cajero en NetBeans y no estoy pudiendo en la sentencia de ingresar el número 0 en el usuario y que informe “GRACIAS POR USAR NUESTRO SISTEMA”, copio el código para ver que puedo estar haciendo mal, muchas gracias.

Realizar un programa que cuando ingrese me pida (por pantalla o por consola) un nombre de usuario y una contraseña, en el cual cuando yo ingrese un cero en un usuario, el sistema automáticamente se cierre (esta será la única manera de cerrar el programa), mostrándome un mensaje de “GRACIAS POR USAR NUESTRO SISTEMA”.

Sino le coloco un cero, el sistema me validará tanto que ingrese un usuario y una contraseña válidos, los cuales tendré que tener antes previamente cargados (ya que no manejamos bases de datos).

Luego de ingresar mi nombre de usuario y mi contraseña, y de haberlos validado, el sistema me mostrara un mensaje de Bienvenida usuario: ………….(El nombre del usuario) Luego ya de haber ingresado, este me preguntará que acción quiero realizar

```
public class BancoCajeroUTN {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String usuario = "";
    int contraseña = 0;
    int contraseña1 = 123;
    String usuario1 = "Federico";
    String usuario2 = "0";
    int cero = Integer.parseInt(usuario2);




    System.out.println("*******************************************");
    System.out.println("*****Bienvenido al cajero de Banco UTN*****");
    System.out.println("*******************************************");
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Ingrese el Usuario: ");
    usuario = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Ingrese la Contraseña: ");
    contraseña = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");


    if (usuario.equals(usuario1) && contraseña == contraseña1) {

        System.out.println("Bienvenido Usuario: " + usuario1);

    } else if (!usuario.equals(usuario1) || contraseña != contraseña1) {

        System.out.println("ERROR DE USUARIO O CONTRASEÑA");

    } else if (usuario.equals(usuario2)) {

        System.out.println("GRACIAS POR USAR NUESTRO SISTEMA");

    } else {

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: y cuál es el problema?

Comment: Muy por arriba, veo que aparentemente necesitas meter esa lógica dentro de un ciclo (loop). Tal como está el código, sólo pedirá datos una vez y luego saldrá, independientemente de que hayas escrito un 0 o no.

Answer (score 0):

jajaja creo que tu problema es de logica tienes un else if que se va cumplir siempre que no pongas tu usuario **Federico** debes poner diferente de `usuario2` algo asi debe quedar

```
if (usuario.equals(usuario1) && contraseña == contraseña1) {

    System.out.println("Bienvenido Usuario: " + usuario1);

} else if ((!usuario.equals(usuario1) || contraseña != contraseña1)&&!usuario.equals(usuario2)) {

    System.out.println("ERROR DE USUARIO O CONTRASEÑA");

} else if (usuario.equals(usuario2)) {

    System.out.println("GRACIAS POR USAR NUESTRO SISTEMA");

} else {

}
```

Pero esto solo soluciona el problema que estas pidiendo

Suerte xD

Answer (score 0):

BuenasFede aqui te pongo tu código más algunas correciones.

Lo que encontré fue:

- Tomabas dos veces los datos del usuario, creo que uno es para leer los datos del usuario de salida y otro el usuario que ingresa al sistema.
- no uses valores posibles como nombres de variables
- Siempre trata de dividir el código en funciones, te va a ahorrar horas de debuggeo y dolores de cabeza, ademas que es mas facil de leer.

  ```
  package com.stack.overflow;

  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Main {
      final static String NOMBRE_USUARIO_DE_SALIDA = "0";

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          /*
          String usuario = "";
          int contraseña = 0;
          int contraseña1 = 123;
          String usuario1 = "Federico";
          String usuario2 = "0";
          int cero = Integer.parseInt(usuario2); <-- no uses valores posibles como nombres de variables
          */
          Usuario defecto = new Usuario("", 0); //No te hace falta crearlo
          Usuario fede = new Usuario("Federico", 123);

          /*
          System.out.println("*******************************************");
          System.out.println("*****Bienvenido al cajero de Banco UTN*****");
          System.out.println("*******************************************");
          System.out.println("");
          */
          mostrarBienvenida();
          /*
          System.out.println("Ingrese el Usuario: ");
          usuario = in.nextLine();
          System.out.println("");

          System.out.println("Ingrese la Contraseña: ");
          contraseña = in.nextInt();
          System.out.println("");
          */

          Usuario user = ingresarUsuario();

          if (user.equals(fede)) {
              System.out.println("Bienvenido Usuario: " + user.getNombre());

          } else if (user.getNombre().equals(NOMBRE_USUARIO_DE_SALIDA)) {
              System.out.println("GRACIAS POR USAR NUESTRO SISTEMA");

          } else {
              /*Cambie el orden para que el caso error*/
              System.out.println("ERROR DE USUARIO O CONTRASEÑA");
          }

          System.out.println("Bye!");
      }

      /**
       * Mustra un mensaje de bienvenida
       */
      private static void mostrarBienvenida() {
          System.out.println("*********************************************");
          System.out.println("***** Bienvenido al cajero de Banco UTN *****");
          System.out.println("*********************************************");
          System.out.println("");
      }

      private static Usuario ingresarUsuario() {
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.println("Ingrese el Usuario: ");
          String usuario = scanner.nextLine();
          System.out.println("");

          System.out.println("Ingrese la Contraseña: ");
          int contraseña = scanner.nextInt();
          System.out.println("");

          Usuario obtenido = new Usuario(usuario, contraseña);

          return obtenido;
      }
  }

  /**
   * Representa u usuario
   */
  class Usuario {
      String nombre;
      int password;

      /**
       * Constructor
       *
       * @param nombre
       * @param pass
       */
      public Usuario(String nombre, int pass) {
          this.nombre = nombre;
          this.password = pass;
      }

      public String getNombre() {
          return nombre;
      }

      public void setNombre(String nombre) {
          this.nombre = nombre;
      }

      public int getPassword() {
          return password;
      }

      public void setPassword(int password) {
          this.password = password;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object obj) {
          if (this == obj) {
              return true;
          }
          if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
              return false;
          } else {
              Usuario otro = (Usuario) obj;
              return this.nombre.equals(otro.nombre) &&
                      this.password == otro.password;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Sigue intentando y no pares de codear! :D